# How to create grid and place elements randomly inside column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive grid that is created with js and css. Inside each column in the grid I want to place elements (the red squares), but the squares should be placed randomly and only inside some of the columns. There is 50 columns, so let's say I want to place 20 squares randomly inside columns so that the squares can't overlap. How do I achieve this in the best way?

js

```
var grid = document.getElementById("grid");

for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var square = document.createElement("div");
    square.className = 'square';
    grid.appendChild(square);

    var child = document.createElement("div");
    child.className = 'child';
    square.appendChild(child);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/pkec93xr/)

Answer (score 1):

First add an ID to each square, then the idea is to generate a random number between 0 and 49 to be able to access those squares. Each time you add a square, you have to store its index to check whether it has already been added. Only stop until 20 squares is added.

```js
var field = document.getElementById("field");

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var square = document.createElement("div");
  square.className = 'square';
  square.id = 'square' + i;
  field.appendChild(square);
}

var squaresPlaced = []; // Stores the squares index placed

while (squaresPlaced.length < 20) { // Stop only if 20 squares is added
  var randomIndex = parseInt(49 * Math.random()); // Generate a random number between 0 and 49

  // Only add the square if it doesn't exist already
  if (squaresPlaced.indexOf(randomIndex) === -1) {
    squaresPlaced.push(randomIndex);
    document.getElementById('square' + randomIndex).style.borderColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#field {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#field>div.square {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#field>div.circle {
  font-size: 1rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="field"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look at it and try it out!

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER UPDATE**

> is it possible to prevent a circle to appear next to another?

Yes, it's enough to change how to generate random numbers. Change this line:

```
if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
```

to:

```
if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1 || arr.indexOf(randomnumber + 1) > -1
                    || arr.indexOf(randomnumber - 1) > -1) continue;
```

> Also if I want to add more shapes, can I just create and append another shape and then clone that in the foreach?

Yes. I added an oval figure.

My proposal is:

- generate 20 random different numbers
- clone and move the circle adjusting the size
- hide all generated circles:

```js
var field = document.getElementById("field");

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var square = document.createElement("div");
    square.className = 'square';
    field.appendChild(square);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var circle = document.createElement("div");
    circle.className = (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? 'circle' : 'oval';
    field.appendChild(circle);
}


var arr = [];
while (arr.length < 20) {
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 50) - 1;
    if (arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1 || arr.indexOf(randomnumber + 1) > -1
            || arr.indexOf(randomnumber - 1) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}

arr.forEach(function (rnd, idx) {
    $('#field > .circle, #field > .removed, #field > .oval, #field > .ovalremoved').eq(rnd)
            .css({border: '1px solid #0000cc'}).clone()
            .css({width: '100%', height: '100%'})
            .appendTo($('.square').eq(rnd));
})
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#field {
    width: 60vw;
    height: 60vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#field > div.square {
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

div.circle {
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

div.oval {
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    border-radius: 100px / 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="field"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is it possible to prevent a circle to appear next to another? Like hide the closest or something like that to make them look more spread out in the grid? Also if I want to add more shapes, can I just create and append another shape and then clone that in the foreach?

Comment: Thank you! Right now circles and ovals can be placed straight under one another for example, making them appear in a row. I was wondering if there's a way to prevent a shape to be placed straight next to another. If I place a shape in a column, then the column next to this is always empty? Hope my explanation is a bit clearer.

Comment: @jdo Sorry. No. the aim of the snippet is only to show how to place in a random way shapes into the chessboard avoiding to use two consecutive cells. There are a lot of possibilities on how place the shapes. Thanks so much

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers and explanations! I have a question though, in the example, the grid gets filled with some shapes but some of the shapes gets "pushed" out of the grid and appear under it. Why is that?